# result is generating null while subtracting two variables

Tags: mysql, datetime, variables, null, subtraction

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK('2018/08/15');
SET @STARTDATE = '2017/08/15';
SET @ENDDATE = '2018/08/15';

  #1->part1


 SET @SEC_IN_START_DATE = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@STARTDATE);
 SET @SEC_IN_END_DATE = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@ENDDATE);
 SELECT @NUM_OF_DAYS = (@SEC_IN_END_DATE - @SEC_IN_START_DATE);
 SELECT @NUM_OF_WEEKS = (@NUM_OF_DAYS%7);  
 SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@ENDDATE);  
 #part-2
 SELECT 
     ROUND((
          (unix_timestamp(@END_DATE) - unix_timestamp(@START_DATE) ) 
          /(24*60*60)
              -7+WEEKDAY(@START_DATE)-WEEKDAY(@END_DATE)
          )/7);
```

all the parts shown above when executed gives the value null[the image shows execution of part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Wff.png) & [the image shows execution of part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIwdr.png)
but both gives null,please help.
thankyou for your help.

Comment: Results must be posted here, not via links, but clearly one of the input variables was NULL.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are doing operations on string type data type its better if you convert them into date time datatype

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declarations are different than the usage, update your query as  below it works.

```
SELECT 
     ROUND((
          (unix_timestamp(@ENDDATE) - unix_timestamp(@STARTDATE) ) 
          /(24*60*60)
              -7+WEEKDAY(@STARTDATE)-WEEKDAY(@ENDDATE)
          )/7);
```

O/P :

```
 SELECT       ROUND((           (unix_timestamp(@ENDDATE) - unix_timestamp(@STARTDATE) )            /(24*60*60)               -7+WEEKDAY(@STARTDATE)-WEEKDAY(@ENDDATE)           )/7); +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ROUND((           (unix_timestamp(@ENDDATE) - unix_timestamp(@STARTDATE) )            /(24*60*60)               -7+WEEKDAY(@STARTDATE)-WEEKDAY(@ENDDATE)           )/7) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                                      51 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: no change buddy I missed while writing on the stackoverflow

Comment: I tried your same queries, I got the o/p, updated in my answer

Comment: Just try select @ENDDATE after variable declaration, this should return the date

Comment: Hit the queries in three steps (as your parts) here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql_terminal_online.php